# Google Maps style does not apply to the Korea area

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I ran into a problem recently with Google Maps styling.

I used the [Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) to customize the Google Maps, but I realized the style does not apply to areas/tiles near Korea.

This is the static in question:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=33.576299,129.200592&zoom=8&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x640&maptype=roadmap&style=saturation:-50|gamma:2.00

I wonder if this is a bug, or it is a decided behavior?

edit:
this does not only happen to `Static`, it also happens to Google Maps v3 api, this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kh4mg93s/) is [the example on styling the maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple), with a different lag/lat.

Also, this only happens when zoom level is >=7

http://jsfiddle.net/kh4mg93s/

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074142/styling-google-map-of-south-korea

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes , Korea does not support some features offered by Google Map due to national law. Google Map Korea can not be export map data for data centers abroad or including the ability to dynamically change the map image. Many South Korea Maps and services are limited to the domestic uses and Google is striving to make this a better service. For more details here's the original answer in Korean: [**original reply from Google Maps Korea**](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps-ko/AI_0FslsAs4)

Comment: Heh, had the same issue.  Glad this clarifies it.