# Custom Styles not Applying at certain areas

Tags: api, google-maps, dictionary

I have been working with google map api. I have applied custom styles to the map. The custom styles seems to work at all the place except in south korean regions.
When The zoom level is set to 6 the custom styles applies perfectly.

Screenshot where custom style is working http://prntscr.com/oj8537

But when I zoom in little further the custom styles does not work.

Screenshot where custom style is not working  http://prntscr.com/oj85iz

When zoom is set over 7 then it stop working. 
Can anyone help me applying my custom style. Am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that was reported in Google's Issue Tracker. Apparently map tiles in South Korea are pre-rendered and hence cannot be styled.

You can view and star the issue to get updates on it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/35820206

Also see related question: [Google Maps style does not apply to the Korea area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568460/google-maps-style-does-not-apply-to-the-korea-area)