# android Googlemap error on dark mode when zoom

Tags: android, google-maps

If I zoom my country on google map, then map color is changed. 
I want to keep on dark mode.

How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Please see my answer in related https://stackoverflow.com/a/57305877/11742502

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help. :)