# Google Maps SDK for Unity didn't functional on Specific area

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently making Location-based game with Unity3d. But Google Maps SDK for Unity didn't work on my location.

I imported 'GoogleMaps.unitypackage' on my project and opened example scene '02_Fundamentals/MapsService101'. When I push a start button on a editor, 'Base Map Loader' Components will create buildings and road objects via 'Lat Lng' parameters.
The problem is, only I entered a South Korea location, These components creates no object at all.
I tried a different location on USA, Japan, Europe, China... All of location was rendered so well, even if there was a backcountry. But Google Maps SDK didn't render on South Korea location, even the Center of Seoul!
[I entered the location of Seoul station but none of objects created.] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFKLB.png)

Is Google Maps API restrict specific country? Any information about this would be helpful.

Comment: Related question: [Google Maps style does not apply to the Korea area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568460/google-maps-style-does-not-apply-to-the-korea-area)

Comment: okay... I wonder how pokemon go's map is working in korea.

Comment: As per the Google Maps Platform gaming services FAQ, the data coverage on South Korea is supported on Playable Locations API but not available on Maps SDK for Unity: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/gaming/support/faq#whatcountries

Comment: Why API works separately I don't get it :/ But Thanks the information.

Answer (score 0):

South Korea may not be supported yet for this version of the Google Maps API or your preferences may be blocking your location at some locations. Try it with an other computer if you can but most probably it is just unsupported.